# socket.close() sends malformed packet

Tags: google-chrome, websocket

When I close the browser window I get this close-packet (which wireshark and libwebockets understand)

```
WebSocket
1... .... = Fin: True
.000 .... = Reserved: 0x00
.... 1000 = Opcode: Connection Close (8)
0... .... = Mask: False
.000 0010 = Payload length: 2
Payload
    Close: 03e9
    Close: Going Away (1001)
```

When I use *socket.close();* (latest Chrome under Windows) I get this packet which neither wireshark nor libwebockets understand.

```
WebSocket
1... .... = Fin: True
.000 .... = Reserved: 0x00
.... 1000 = Opcode: Connection Close (8)
1... .... = Mask: True
.000 0000 = Payload length: 0
Masking-Key: 1e45aadf
Payload
    Close: <MISSING>
Unmask Payload
[Dissector bug, protocol WebSocket: tvbuff.c:690: failed assertion "DISSECTOR_ASSERT_NOT_REACHED"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, there is actually nothing wrong.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.5.1

> The **Close frame MAY contain a body (the "Application data" portion
> of    the frame) that indicates a reason for closing**, such as an
> endpoint    shutting down, an endpoint having received a frame too
> large, or an    endpoint having received a frame that does not conform
> to the format    expected by the endpoint.  **If there is a body, the
> first two bytes of    the body MUST be a 2-byte unsigned integer (in
> network byte order)    representing a status code with value /code/
> defined in Section 7.4**.    Following the 2-byte integer...

So Google Chrome is sending a Close frame that does not contain a reason, and it is legal. [MAY indicates an optional feature](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2119).

**So it is not malformed, it is just odd.** It is odd because it is a masked frame with no payload, it could set off the mask bit, and save the 4 bytes for the masking key. Also odd because it includes a closing reason when doing `socket.close()`, but it doesn't when closing the browser, although it is legal.

I think it is just an behavior inconsistency in Google Chrome, but still, it should be correctly handled in libwebsockets and wireshark, because it complies with the specification.

Answer (score 1):

Although the `socket.close();` call is perfectly valid, you may want to try `socket.close(1000, "Goodbye from client");` in order to prevent that annoying message in Wireshark.